# Not Implemented Error in coded animation (simplgui)

Tags: python, error-handling

For a current school project, I am making a simple animation and while trying to import threading I keep getting a not implemented error.

The animation is supposed to have two circles moving perpendicular to each other passing back and forth on the screen without colliding. I added threading, time, and simplgui to try to accomplish this but I only received the error message: "NotImplementedError: threading is not yet implemented in Skulpt".

At the very least I need to know what the error message means or an alternative way to accomplish this animation because every forum or coding site I have consulted has not given clear answers on what the issue is.

code:

```
import time
import threading 
import simplegui
x1 = 50
y1 = 200
x2 = 200
y2 = 200
        
def draw_handler(canvas):
    simo()
    def horizontal(use2): 
        def reverse():
            global x1
            while (x1 > 50):
                x1 = x1 - 5
                if (x1 >= 50):
                    x1 = x1 - 5
                canvas.draw_circle((x1, y1), 50, 1, "White", "White")
        
            def forward():
                global x1
                x1 = x1 + 5
                if (x1 >= 350):
                    reverse()
                canvas.draw_circle((x1, y1), 50, 1, "White", "White")
        forward()
    
    #def verticle(use1):
    
    def simo():
        use1 = threading.thread(target=verticle)
        use2 = threading.thread(target=horizontal)

frame = simplegui.create_frame('Testing', 400, 400)
frame.set_canvas_background("Black")
frame.set_draw_handler(draw_handler)
frame.start()
```

Comment: I don't use Skulpt, but the error says that it does not support threading. Have you tried running the code in a regular command window?

Comment: I don't use simplegui either, but there may already be built in timer or animation capabilities built in.

Comment: Some quick testing shows that the draw handler gets called repeatedly to refresh the canvas, so there's no need for a thread at all. https://replit.com/@JohnnyMopp/HastyOnlyOpensource